# Any good profiler for coding in Ansi C for gwan like xhprof for php?

Tags: scripting, profiler, g-wan

Looking for web based c proiler tool similar to xhprof and for Linux. Any good recommendations for gwan scripting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A G-WAN profiler would have to both report issues for:

- code portions of G-WAN scripts (servlets and handlers)
- blocking / poorly written scripts (not using events)
- slow library or system calls, etc.

Rather than making a separate product, it may make more sense to use extra code in G-WAN scripts to check your workflow.

G-WAN provides several [examples](http://gwan.ch/source/httpdate.c) using very precise time functions like: `cycles64()`, `getms()`, `getus()`, and `getns()` to check how fast code portions or library calls are.

But G-WAN also provides server counters like `REQUEST_TIME` which will reveal performance and scalability issues in your applications.

Further, you can go deeper by using a `connection handler` to check the `accept`, `parse`, `build` and `reply` times:

```
enum HANDLER_ACT
{
   HDL_INIT = 0,
   HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT, // just after accept (client IP address setup)
   HDL_AFTER_READ,   // each time a read was done until HTTP request OK
   HDL_BEFORE_PARSE, // HTTP verb/URI validated but not HTTP headers
   HDL_AFTER_PARSE,  // HTTP headers validated, ready to build reply
   HDL_BEFORE_WRITE, // after a reply was built, but before it is sent
   HDL_AFTER_WRITE,  // after a reply was sent
   HDL_HTTP_ERRORS,  // when G-WAN is going to reply with an HTTP error
   HDL_BEFORE_CLOSE, // when G-WAN is going to close a connection
   HDL_CLEANUP
};
```

As G-WAN supports scripts in 17 programming languages, performance tuning may also involve doing the right choices for speed-critical parts of your applications.

You may want to use G-WAN C scripts for generating images on-the-fly and G-WAN PHP, C# or Java scripts for less critical tasks.

G-WAN lets you do that very easily.

Last but not least, G-WAN provides [ab.c](http://gwan.ch/source/ab.c) (an open-source benchmark tool) to let you identify scalability issues, most of which are discussed [here](http://gwan.ch/en_apachebench_httperf.html).

Comment: All is good, the only issue is I actually like the boxes done by graphviz so I'm looking for an equivalent that can do so with c profiling. That'll really make it simple coz I like the visual outlook, which makes finding the next frequently accessed function/module really easy.

Comment: **graphviz** uses a text file using a special format as input. You can generate this text file from a G-WAN script. Note that many Javascript libraries offer similar graph-drawing services.